# Why does Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 and previous versions crash while trying to compile this very simple code employing a unique_ptr?

Tags: stl, visual-studio-2017, icc

I've tried to compile the last version of a library developed by Intel (https://github.com/embree/) using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 with Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 under Windows 7.

I've come across a compilation error that prevented me to go further. I managed to isolate a very simple test case on which this combination of compiler/compiling environment systematically fails. The sample itself is pretty useless:

```
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
}
```

Here is what Visual Studio 2017  outputs:

```
1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : Test2000, Configuration : Debug x64 ------
1>test2000.cpp
1>test2000.cpp(5): error : access violation
1>      std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
1>                              ^
1>
1>compilation aborted for test2000.cpp (code 4)
1>Génération du projet "Test2000.vcxproj" terminée -- ÉCHEC.
========== Génération : 0 a réussi, 1 a échoué, 0 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========
```

I found this quite peculiar and tried it gcc.godbolt.org and was surprised to be able to reproduce the same behaviour on a gcc environment with Intel C++ Compiler 13, 16 and 17 (you can test it by yourself here https://godbolt.org/g/3SXxuH).
ICC's output under a GCC environment is more detailed and basically consists in this error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/bin/../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/move.h(48): error: identifier "__builtin_addressof" is undefined
      { return __builtin_addressof(__r); }
```

My guess is that there is some kind of incompatibility between the last version of the STL headers and Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 (and previous versions too). A quick Google search yielded this only forum post with no answer:
https://www.cpume.com/question/fgshnonz-intel-icc-compile-c-code-cause-error.html

Has anyone met this problem and found a solution (other than switching to Intel C++ Compiler 18.0, of course) before?

Comment: I guess there are some link errors.

Comment: I don't get how such a problem could go undetected like that.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No, sorry, I finally switched to Intel C++ Compiler 18.0.